# React Build Hosting in Apache: Forbidden error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache

Getting 403 Forbidden error while hosting react build app to apache server in ubuntu.

I tried setting up virtual host from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Still getting the error. What should I do?

PS: I have the index.html file in `/var/www/html/build`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `.htaccess` file to the root of your host?
If not, add this to `.htaccess` and then restart apache server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html (in your case /build/index.html)
    RewriteRule ^ /build/index.html
</IfModule>
```

> You have to enable `mod_rewrite` though.

Comment: How can I enable `mod_rewrite`?